# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hide' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have an error when trying to load a fancybox on page load. Says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hide' of undefined` on fancybox-pack.js line 18

My code is:

```
 $.fancybox($('#sample'));
```

Comment: Set you browser to break on errors and examine the call stack.

Comment: What about `$.fancybox('#sample');`? assuming you have a container element with `id="sample"`, which holds the content to be shown in fancybox